# Creating manually a legend in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So this is the graph and the code I have so far:

```
library(fivethirtyeight)
library(tidyverse)

bad_drivers$num_drivers
bad_drivers$perc_speeding

mytable <- bad_drivers %>%
mutate(SpeedPerBilion = (num_drivers * perc_speeding)/100)

ggplot(data = mytable, aes(x = state, y = SpeedPerBilion, fill='red')) +
xlab("") +
ylab("") +
coord_flip() +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
geom_bar(data= mytable, aes(x = state, y=num_drivers), alpha=0.5,stat="identity") +
theme(plot.title =`enter code here` element_text(face = "bold"), legend.position = "none")+
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())+
labs(title = "Drviers Involved In Fatal Collisions While Speeding",
   subtitle = "As a share of the number of fatal collisions per billion miles, 2009")
```

[image]

So my questions are:
How am I adding a legend to this graph?
How to erase this lower y coordinate (so to have just the upper one)?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Hi Đorđe, could you clarify what you would like the legend to look like?

Comment: No, sorry, because I don't have a situation like that. Look at my example.

Comment: My legend should have these 2 colors (red and red with lower opacity) and there should be written what each color represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find code below and what I believe is your desired plot. You will have to tweak labels to match what you need but I put place holder names. The key is using the `scale_fill_manual` with a named vector of colors and calling those color names in the `aes` of each layer you need to use that color in. Also a neat trick is using `alpha()` to apply alpha as a color rather than a separate scale. Finally the y axis transformation you were looking for is `position = "right"` so it ends up on top after `coord_flip()`.

```r
library(fivethirtyeight) # for data
library(tidyverse)

bad_drivers %>%
  mutate(SpeedPerBilion = (num_drivers * perc_speeding)/100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = state, y = SpeedPerBilion)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = "Speeding")) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = state, y = num_drivers, fill = "All"),
           stat = "identity") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Speeding Involved",
                    values = c("Speeding" = alpha("red", 1), "All" = alpha("red", 0.5))) +
  labs(title = "Drviers Involved In Fatal Collisions While Speeding",
       subtitle = "As a share of the number of fatal collisions per billion miles, 2009") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "red", alpha = c(0.25, 1))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note: For some reason the transparency in the legend doesn't look the same as in the plot so I manually set the legend to `alpha = 0.25` so to my eye it matches the plot. Please confirm the result on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
library(fivethirtyeight)
library(tidyverse)

mytable <- bad_drivers %>%
  mutate(SpeedPerBilion = (num_drivers * perc_speeding)/100)

ggplot(data = mytable, aes(x = state, y = SpeedPerBilion, fill='red')) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_bar(data= mytable, aes(x = state, y=num_drivers), alpha=0.5,stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x.bottom = element_blank())+
  labs(title = "Drviers Involved In Fatal Collisions While Speeding",
       subtitle = "As a share of the number of fatal collisions per billion miles, 2009")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey, It's good but in the legend I need to have 2 colors as presented on the graph :D